# Changing the width of column filter textbox in Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

```
function showjson() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "json/abc.json", // Path of json file
        dataType: "json", // Type of data which is being fetched
        type: "post", // Method used Post
        success: function (data) // function to check whether the json data
        // has no error
        {
            var len = data.data.length; // to find length
            var str = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                // To Display The values in Datatable
                str += "<tr align = center>" + "<td>" + "<input type=" + data.data[i].check + ">" + "</td>" + "<td>" + data.data[i].id + "</td>" + "<td>" + data.data[i].name + "</td>" + "<td>" + data.data[i].type + "</td>" + "<td>" + data.data[i].attribute + "</td>" + "<td>" + data.data[i].sku + "</td>" + "<td>" + data.data[i].price + "</td>" + "<td>" + data.data[i].quantity + "</td>" + "<td>" + data.data[i].visibility + "</td>" + "<td>" + data.data[i].status + "</td>" + "<td>" + data.data[i].websites + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<A href='newProduct.jsp'>" + data.data[i].action + "</A>" + "</td>" + "</tr>";
            }
            $(str).appendTo('#tbl');
            $("#tbl").dataTable({
                "iDisplayLength": 50,
                    "bAutoWidth": false,
                    "sDom": '<"top"l>rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">', // Disables only
                // Global Search
                /* "bFilter": false, */
                // Disables the all search Option
                "bSortCellsTop": true
            }).columnFilter({
                sPlaceHolder: "head:after",
                aoColumns: [

                type: "select",
                values: ["yes", "No", "Any"]
                },
                {
                    type: "number-range",
                    sWidth: "50px"
                },
                {
                    type: "text",
                    sWidth: "50px"

                },
                {
                    type: "select",
                    values: ["Simple", "Grouped ",
                        "Configurable", "Virtual",
                        "Bundle ", "Downloadable"]
                },
                {
                    type: "select",
                    values: ["Default", "Clothing", "CPU",
                        "Electronics", "Jewellery",
                        "Laptops"]
                },
                {
                    type: "text",
                    sWidth: "50px"
                },
                {
                    type: "number-range",
                    sWidth: "50px"
                },
                {
                    type: "number-range",
                    sWidth: "50px"
                },
                {
                    type: "select",
                    values: ["Catalog", "Search",
                        "Catalog Search"]
                },
                {
                    type: "select",
                    values: ["enabled", "disabled"]
                },
                {
                    type: "select",
                    values: ["Main Website"]
                },
                ]
            });

    },
    error: function (data) // function if the json has wrong syntax
    {
        alert("error"); // Alerts a msg
    }
    });
}
```

---

In the above code i am taking values from JSON dynamically.The Table is converting into datatable.But Because of Many number of columns in table.The tables is width is too much because of large width of column filter.

```
<!-- DataTable Start Here -->
<div id="div3">
    <table id="tbl" class="dis" style="font-size: 12px; height: 50px;" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr id="t1">
                <th></th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Attrib. Set Name</th>
                <th>SKU</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Visibility</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Websites</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="t2">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

My Json File From where my data data is been retrieved

```
{
    "data": [{
        "check": "checkbox class=case name=case",
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Alex",
            "type": "Simple Product",
            "attribute": "Laptops",
            "sku": 349,
            "price": "$125",
            "quantity": 5000,
            "visibility": "Search",
            "status": "Enabled",
            "websites": "Main Websites",
            "action": "[Edit]"
    }, {
        "check": "checkbox class=case name=case",
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Kravina",
            "type": "Grouped Product",
            "attribute": "Default",
            "sku": 125,
            "price": "$125",
            "quantity": 5656,
            "visibility": "Catalog",
            "status": "Enabled",
            "websites": "Main Websites",
            "action": "[Edit]"
    }]
}
```

My only problem is that I am unable to decrease the width of the column filter search box. I have used `{swidth:"50px"}` but it is not working. Please tell me way so that i can change the width of my column filter in datatable. Also Please let me know if plugins required if any.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding or overriding below css :

```
.number_range_filter
{
  width:50px;
}
```